# Проверить подлинность сертификата

Tags: ios, ssl, apple

Есть [сертификат](https://sandbox.gc.apple.com/public-key/gc-sb-2.cer).

Не пойму как сделать [вот это](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLocalPlayer/generateIdentityVerificationSignatureWithCompletionHandler).

Как проверить, что публичный ключ этого сертификата, подписан компанией `Apple`?